# Find the minimal surface, integral over which for some function gives a certain value

Tags: real-analysis

So here is the problem:

Let's say we have some function $f(x,y)$

And we have some value $a$, where $a =\int_S f(x,y)dxdy$

From the set of surfaces $\{S\}$ where the above is true, find the minimal $S'$. I realise that this might possibly be non-unique, so here are some constraints: the surface $S$ is defined as:

$a =\int_S f(x,y)dxdy = \int_{0}^{g(x)}\int_{0}^{b}f(x,y)dxdy$

i.e a trapezoid where one of the sides is $g(x)$

So just find $g(x)$ which minimizes the surface $S'$ for which above is true (integral of f(x,y) evaluated over the surface S gives a)

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but perhaps using the [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) will help in the trapezoid constrained case.

Comment: Do we have any regularity hypothesis on $f$ ? Continuity or compact support for example? If you don't mind $S$ to not be a trapezoid maybe it could be easier to prove that the solution is unique, if there is one